# I am having trouble understanding Characters....

Tags: character-creation

Hi guys as my first post. i am very new to DnD i have created a quest and a world filled it with 30 towns, i have sat for weeks on end designing a back story for each of my 5 group members and have interlinked them to each other to enhance the final plot line. i just have problems setting up my Characters. i would like to keep them balanced starting at level 10 (due to back story reasons) i have never been able to grasp the concept on paper if i could put it that way. any suggestions?

i do realize i might be going off tangent with some of the chars

Half-Orc - Barbarian

Halfing - Mage

Human - Rogue/Ranger

Elf - Thief

Human - Fighter

any help suggestions or anything please let me know

Comment: If you could tag this (or comment and we will) with the D&D edition you are playing of D&D.

Comment: What are you asking?

Comment: I don't understand the question either. It sounds like you're pre-making the player characters? (You can do that, but it's unusual for a long-term game; normally only one-shot demos use pregenerated characters.) And you want... some kind of overview of how to make characters? That's all I can really make out, so some more information about what exactly you need help with would improve things.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie i pre-making the players characters as i need them to each have a certain backstory that connects them to each player somehow without the players knowing. due to the fact that they have a backstory i would like them to start at level 4 (sorry i put 10 before) my question is what is the best way to do the leveling before game starts and to keep it balanced (as i said new to this) which is the best version to use and best stats on each of the characters i have given. sorry if i confused with the way i ask. we all new and would like to start i just enjoy creating the story,

Comment: Why don't you just make the 1st-level version of the characters and then let the players do the levelling up to 4th level? Especially since they need to learn too.